# Extract number from string by matching the prefix

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell contains this value/text :

```
T50 EX3 OF2 BE40 BL10 ZLD6 ZLS2 ZRS10 AA1
```

How to get the number with the 'EX' prefix ? in this case i want to extract that '3' from EX3.

Also, this number can be any digit, for example it can be :

```
EX112
```

or

```
EX00078
```

How to extract that '112' and '00078' and make it as number 112 and 78 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `regexextract()` like this:

`=iferror( value( regexextract(A2, "\bEX(\d+)") ) )`

The `value()` wrapper converts to number, and `iferror()` guards against cells that do not contain an "EX" sequence.

To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).